# How to make a URL displayed in Activeadmin clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, activeadmin

In one of my `ActiveAdmin` pages I have fields containing a URL (either https: or file:). How can I make that when clicked on a new browser tab opens with the corresponding content ? 
I tried

```rb
link_to('site web', :siteWeb)
```

but the result is an error message:

```rb
undefined method `siteWeb_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f048201edb0>:0x00007f048202f700>
```

Comment: Greetings. What is `:siteWeb` in your case?

Comment: "How do I make a link that opens in another tab?", `link_to 'Link text', '/path', target: "_blank", rel: "noreferrer noopener"`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

Comment: :siteWeb is a string containing a URL

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your using a path helper that isn't defined in your `routes.rb` file. There's an easy way to see what the right path helper is though, just go to your terminal and run:

```
rails routes
```

You'll get a bunch of information about each route, along with the specific name of the route path helper function defined in Rails. Then you can just use it like so: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Sorry I' lost. My understanding is that paths and routes are related to Rails _resources_ that are related to _models_. But what I am trying to do in the _show page_ of one of my resource is just a stupid reference to something like `www.google.com` (ore more reasonable `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8YB47by5g4`).